# Issues with adding images to JFrames

Tags: java, image, swing, embedded-resource, imageicon

I have been trying to load imageicons into a jframe. I have no idea why this code doesn't work. I have tried using jpanels and jlabels, and also other ways of loading images, but those don't work either. I think because of this it has something to do with my JFrame that I set up . I would like to stay away from  jpanels and jlabels, because at least as far as my knowledge goes, they cannot be scaled. If anyone has a solution to adding the images, please tell me. here is the code:

```
import java.awt.Canvas;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Base extends Canvas implements Runnable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 001;
    private Image rock1;
    private Image rock2;
    private Image wood1;

    private Thread thread;
    private boolean running = (false);
    private boolean paused = (false);

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int z = 512;


    private void start() {
        if (running)
            return;
        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
    }

    public void run(){}

    public Base(){}

    public static void main(String[] Args) {
        Base game = new Base();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setTitle("Game");

        System.out.println("Running...");

        game.start();
        game.loadPics();

    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            x = x - 5;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            x = x + 5;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
            y = y - 5;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT) {
            y = y + 5;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            z = z + 5;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            z = z - 5;
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            paused = (true);
        }
    }

    public void loadPics(){

        rock1 = new ImageIcon("C\\...\\rock1.png").getImage();
        rock2 = new ImageIcon("C\\...\\rock2.png").getImage();
        wood1 = new ImageIcon("C\\....\\wood1.png").getImage();

        repaint();
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        while(paused = false){
        g.drawImage(rock1, x, y, z, z, this);
        g.drawImage(rock2, x + 512, y, z, z, this);
        g.drawImage(wood1, x, y + 512, z, z, this);

        try{
            Thread.sleep(16);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        g.dispose();
        }

    }
}
```

Again, I think the problem lies with my JFrame, but I can't be too sure since I am not the most experienced java programmer. Anyway, if you know a solution or what to change, please help.

Comment: 1) `"C\\...\\rock1.png"`  Is that what is in the code, literally?  Try doing `File f = new File("C\\...\\rock1.png"); System.out.println("Exists? " + file.exists());`.  These resources should typically be loaded by URL rather than by file.  It is discussed around every 12 hours on SO. 2) Use all Swing components. 3) Use a `javax.swing.Timer` to invoke `repaint()` rather than a `Thread` and `sleep(n)`. 4) Don't dispose of a `Graphics` instance unless you created it yourself.

Answer (score 5):

This statement

```
while (paused = false){
```

will always evaluate to `false` as you're using an assignment expression, so the subsequent calls to `drawImage` won't occur. You probably meant to  use the `==` operator to compare the primitive `boolean` value:

```
while (paused == false){
```

- Don't use `paint`, Use `paintComponent` from a subclassed `JComponent`
- Don't call `Thread.sleep` in *any* `paint` method. Swing has its own [concurrency mechanisms](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). Instead of calling `Thread.sleep` here, you could use a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to periodically perform graphical updates.

Aside from that, AWT are heavyweight components are don't render well with lightweight Swing components. Use [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than `Key Listeners` for Swing applications.

Answer (score 0):

I have had many recurring problems like this and have developed a way to solve this.
First of all, your `public class Base` needs to be double buffered. Change method `paint(Graphics g)` to `paintComponent(Graphics g)`. Add a new `paint(Graphics g)` method and add this code:

```
 public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub (IGNORE!!!)

    dbi = createImage (getWidth(),getHeight());
    dbg = dbi.getGraphics();
    paintComponent(dbg);
    g.drawImage(dbi , 0 , 0 , this);

 }
```

And at the top of `public class Base`, add these variables:

```
 private Image dbi;
 private Graphics dbg;
```

This automatically calls `paintComponent(Graphics g)` and has completed the first step.

Next, remove the try statement in `paintComponent()` and write this in `run()`

```
@Override
public void run() {

    try {

        while (true) {

            Thread.sleep(5); // we want this so the computer doesn't go too fast

        }

    } catch (Exception e) { // Never have an empty catch statement

        System.out.println ("Error! stacktrace: ");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}
```

The `@Override` annotation *has* to be there or it **will not** repaint.

The next part is crititcal:
before anything else, put `super.paint(g);` at the top of `paintComponent(Graphics g)`
and `repaint();` at the bottom.

This should have solved it, but there are some potential problems I found;

- JFrame initialization

  ```
  public Base(){

      add(game);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setSize(800, 600);
      setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      setResizable(false);
      setVisible(true);
      setTitle("Game");

      start();
      loadPics();

  }

  public static void main(String[] Args) { // Makes game smoother

      Base base = new Base ();
      Thread t = new Thread (base);
      t.start();

  }
  ```
- Remove `private void start()` as this does not affect game play.
- Check the file directories, as they may be incorrect. **Hint: C\ doesn't cut it. It's C:\**

Hope it works out and happy coding!